# How to assign colors to column categories in bubble plot (meta package) in R

Tags: r, colors, bubble-chart

Full disclosure, I am not the best at coding in R, so this may be a dummy question.

I am working with a bubble plot using the packages metafor, dmetar, and meta in R. I have some effect sizes that are assigned to specific categories and I am plotting them with rainfall/precipitation as a category on the x axis using a metaregression model.

I want to assign colors to a column found in my csv file. However, the code is not recognizing this and is randomly assigning colors. I am having hard time searching online too, as this is not through ggplot2.

My code is currently:

```
bubble(output.metareg.precipitation,
       xlab = "Difference in total monthly precipitation (mm)",
       ylab = "Effect Size",
       col.line = TRUE,
       col=TRUE,
       pch = 21,
       min.cex = 0.2,
       max.cex = 2,
       studlab = FALSE)
```

Everything shows up in grey color. I also tried experimenting with brewer.pal:

```
bubble(output.metareg.precipitation,
       xlab = "Difference in total monthly precipitation (mm)",
       ylab = "Effect Size",
       col=brewer.pal(12,"Spectral"),
       pch = 21,
       bg = brewer.pal(12,"Spectral"),
       min.cex = 0.2,
       max.cex = 2,
       studlab = FALSE)
```

And then the plot has some nice colors! But they are of course randomly assigned.

I have 12 categories that I want to assign colors to within the column. I would like to to write my script in a way that that the categories within column are each assigned a color. Ideally, I would also like to add a legend.

How would I go about this? Perhaps I need to convert the categories into number values?

Thank you in advance for your help! I hope I posted this correctly.

Comment: Unlike `ggplot2`, base plots usually expect a vector of colors of the same length as the data. So if your data had a column you wanted to color by, with values `"a", "b", "a"`, the color argument would be something like `"red", "blue", "red"`. So you'll probably need to build that vector of colors based on your data and your palette and pass it to the `col` argument.

Comment: If you need help doing that, please share a little bit of sample data to make your question reproducible. `dput()` is the nicest way to do this as it is copy/pasteable and contains all the class and structure info, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.